# Qt QML new project creation error (Only ".pro" file can be seen)

Tags: qt, qml

When i was creating a new project for my QT Qml program i noticed that the only file that can be seen is the .pro file of the Qt QML project application.
(Only a single file will be seen which is the .pro file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you do not have that yellow exclamation mark sign before your project name in the **Editor**.

If you do, configure your project.
Click on the " **Projects** " button on the left (above "**Help**" and under " **Debug** "), select your kits, and click and the " **Configure Project** " button on the right part of the screen.

If you still have this problem, select a different compiler in " **Build & Run** ". (Ex: *Desktop Qt 5.13.0 MinGW 64-bit*).

I also had this problem for non-QML applications, but I do not really know why either.
Note that you may need to try different compilers.

Comment: Thank you that really helped me. For those who has these kinds of problems just check which compilers you're using to Build & Run your projects.